# using telerik RadRibbonView for navigation seems clunky

Tags: wpf, telerik

The telerik RadRibbonView (RRV) gives me exactly the display I need,

[image]

but I have not been able to find the built-in way to use it for navigation - for getting the area below the RRV to change content when one of the buttons is clicked.  - the App Database, Server Setup, About, Help buttons.

The buttons are in the XAML like this:

```
<te:RadRibbonTab Header="Smart Objects" x:Name="SmartObjectsTab"
    <te:RadRibbonGroup Width="Auto">
        <te:RadRibbonButton Click="SmrtObjMenuButtonClicked"
        <te:RadRibbonButton Click="SmrtObjMenuButtonClicked"
```

Currently I have a ContentContol below the RRV and when a button is clicked I change the ContentTemplate for that in the codebehind.  It works but I don't think its the right way.

So what is the built-in, wpf/telerik way to use the RadRibbonView for navigation - for getting the area below the RRV to change content when one of the buttons is clicked.

Thanks

Comment: Nice info... What is your question ?

Comment: I don't think that the purpose of RadRibbonView is for navigation. When that is said, then there is no correct or uncorrect way of doing thing. If a ContentControl is working for you then it is the correct way. Perhaps you should consider a Frame instead. Frame os more meant for Navigation, with it's  built in feature for navigation.

Comment: @Nawed, I agree.  It is like I am forcing RadRibbonView to support navigation.  Telerik shouldn't list it under Navigation in their docs - https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/introduction

A Frame doesn't seem like a navigation control either.  I guess I would use some kind of menu bar with it?

Comment: Maybe you should turn your question around and tell what you really need ? If you really want Navigation control with it's navigation possibilities, like Next, Previous then Frame is your friend. Otherwise ContenControl is the correct control. Check blog for some info regarding navigation http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-navigation

Comment: @Naweed, Thanks friend.  Your comments got me on the right track.  I am using a TabControl in a Window.  I plan to use a Frame in each tab's content and the buttons will use MyFrame.Navigate.  The blog that you sent me to was very helpful.  If you want to put that stuff in a response I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The RadRibbonView control provides you with the means of creating the navigation UI and the interface to navigate via the UI. However, what the navigation would do and how exactly it will be implemented is up to you.

The general approach that I would suggest you is to create commands that changes the views and bind them to the Command property of the ribbon buttons. For example you can have a ContentControl that shows your views (as in your current implementation). And if we accept that we are following the MVVM pattern, you can change the view model set as Content of the ContentControl each time you click a button. In this case to show different views for each view model you can use the ContentTemplateSelector of the ContentControl.

Regards,
Martin